# getopts optional and no optional arguments

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, getopts

Having problems with my getopts function to work properly.  What should happened is that if no agruments are given, then everything is defaulted.  I have four options as follows:

-b that needs a value of either one of the two 2048 or 4096 otherwise usage.

-c needs a value of path otherwise usage.

-p needs a value of path otherwise usage

-h which does need a value which is ignored even it does.

But if I leave off a option, it won't allow me to continue. So I need to be able to put 0 to 4.

```
msg=""
nginx_ssl_conf=/etc/nginx/nginx-ssl.conf
BIT_SIZE=2048 
isHardened=false
hardened_ciphers="'ECDH+AESGCM256:DH+AESGCM256:ECDH+AES256:SH+AES256:RSA+AESGCM256:RSA+AES256:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH';"
DHEC_path=$STORAGE_ROOT/ssl/dhparam.pem


# Usage info
usage() {
cat << EOF
Usage: ${0##*/} [-h] [-p DIR_DHEC_KEY] [-b BIT_SIZE]  [-c DIR_NGINX_SSL]...
This script generates and enables DHEC for Nginx.  Defaulted to 2048 key.
Hardened mode will generate 4096 key and the following cipher suites:
'ECDH+AESGCM256:DH+AESGCM256:ECDH+AES256:SH+AES256:RSA+AESGCM256:RSA+AES256:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH'

    -h          Enable hardened ciphers and 4096 bit key.
    -p          Specify dir to generate the DHEC key.
    -c          Specify dir nginx ssl conf is. 
    -b          Specify the bit size to generate.
EOF
exit 1
}  


while getopts "::b:h:::p::c" opt ; do
    case "${opt}" in
        b)
            BIT_SIZE=${OPTARG}
            if [ -z "${b}"]; then
               usage
            fi
            ;;
        h)
            isHardened=true
            BIT_SIZE=4096 
            ;;
    p)
            DHEC_path=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        c)
            nginx_ssl_conf=${OPTARG}
            ;;

        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Comment: bash `getopts` doesn't do optional arguments as far as I know. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035 (and the linked getopts tutorial) for various ways to handle arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change what you have with this:

```
while getopts "hb:c:p:" opt ; do
    case "${opt}" in
        b)
            BIT_SIZE=${OPTARG}
            if [ -z "${BIT_SIZE}" ]; then
               usage
            fi
            ;;
```

Note I changed the `getopts` argument, fixed the `${b}` invalid variable, and added the requisite space before the `]` in the `b)` case.

That should get you closer. I'm not 100% I follow your use case, and what I do understand I think I might approach differently.  For example, as you have it written now, `-b 2048 -h` produces a different `BIT_SIZE` than you and the user might expect. (Compare it with `-h -b 2048` to see what I mean: argument order shouldn't matter with flags, typically.)

**Edit**
To use the `-b` bit value if given, otherwise use the `-h` bit value if given, otherwise to use a default, the relevant changes I'd make are:

```
DEFAULT_BIT_SIZE=2048
isHardened="false"

while getopts "hb:c:p:" opt ; do
    case "${opt}" in
        b)
            BIT_SIZE=${OPTARG}
            if [ -z "${BIT_SIZE}" ]; then
               usage
            fi
            ;;
        h)
            isHardened="true"
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ -z "${BIT_SIZE}" -a "true" == "${isHardened}" ]; then
    BIT_SIZE=4096
elif [ -z "${BIT_SIZE}" ]; then
    BIT_SIZE=$DEFAULT_BIT_SIZE
fi
```

Comment: I would like the -b to override any default setting. So if the user uses -h which defaults to 4096 and -b is used then whatever the -b is.  How would you approach that?

Comment: The three arguments that need a value if used are -b -p -c otherwise usage and exit

Comment: Alright, the skeleton code in my edit should get you what you want.  Add back in your `p`, `c`, and `*` cases and that should do it.

Comment: Thanks I think this covers most situations. Thank you! I put a complete script for code review. If you want take a look. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63456/updating-a-config-file

Comment: I would not suggest using the `false` and `true` builtin's that way. There is no reason to do so and it makes breaking the script for someone who sees an unquoted variable and doesn't understand what is going on much too easy.

Comment: @EtanReisner: I agree, but I didn't want to go too far afield with my edits to the original.

Comment: Fair enough. I hadn't noticed them in the original (skimming) and as they aren't actually used in the snippet they might have been used as strings there (and in fact they are, see the codereview link).

Comment: @EtanReisner: Edited mine so as to not confuse passerbys.

Comment: @user3590149: You're getting that behavior because of what @EtanReisner was mentioning in the comments recently.  Basically don't use `true` and `false`: use "true" and "false".  See my updated answer.

Comment: BIT_SIZE=DEFAULT_BIT_SIZE  This doesn't evaluate how you want it to. I think its suppose to be 'BIT_SIZE=$DEFAULT_BIT_SIZE' Does that make sense?

Comment: @user3590149: Yes, that was a typo. I've fixed it.  You're welcome!  Thanks for your vote!

Comment: Using `isHardened=false` is fine. As is assigning `true` later. It is using them unquoted in command context that was the "problem".

Comment: @EtanReisner Yep, and IMO it's generally easier on novice bash scripters to just steer clear of unquoted altogether and keep them quoted everywhere.